# Swift - Programatically add/remove Constraint for specific view

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

i'm trying to use a infoView which opens once tapped on the info button. See picture:

[image]

i would like the infoView to be vertical aligned with the button pressed.
I have a UIbutton collection.
Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet var infoButtons: [UIButton]!

@IBAction func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var alignYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
         alignYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: infoButtons[0], attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([alignYConstraint])
        infoView.isHidden = false
        infoView.textView.text = "Text goes here"
        infoView.onClickCallback = {
            self.infoView.isHidden = true
            //                    self.infoView.removeFromSuperview()
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([alignYConstraint])
        }
    case 2:
         alignYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: infoButtons[1], attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([alignYConstraint])
        infoView.isHidden = false
        infoView.textView.text = "Different text"
        infoView.onClickCallback = {
            self.infoView.isHidden = true
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([alignYConstraint])
        }
    ....................
    }
}
```

I have two issues:

1) if I click on the close button everything works perfectly but if I click on another info button before closing the infoView then I have conflicting constraints and the view won't align as requested. I've tried to remove the previous constraint... but apparently I can't make it a success.

2) I am trying to close the infoView even if i Tap anywhere outside the infoView, but also here same problem: conflicting constraints and the view won't align with the correct button

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved by adding an array.

I initialised an array at beginning of the class (var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint ) , then i add every time i click the constraints into the array. 
Every time i click a button i check if the array is empty. If it's not i remove the constraint. Here's the code:

```
if sender.tag == 1{
        if constraint.count > 0 {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraint)
            constraint.removeAll()
        }
        let alignYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: infoButtons[0], attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([alignYConstraint])
        constraint.append(alignYConstraint)
        infoView.isHidden = false
        infoView.textView.text = "Text goes here"
        infoView.onClickCallback = {
            self.infoView.isHidden = true
            //self.infoView.removeFromSuperview()
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([alignYConstraint])
        }
    }else if sender.tag == 2 {
        if constraint.count > 0 {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraint)
            constraint.removeAll()
        }
.............
```